# Calculus exercise differentials

Tags: calculus

You can find the exercise in the link below. 
In my opinion I need to create a sum like (f(x) - 1)^2 but I can not find out how
https://www.dropbox.com/s/m2fxwd860oqvfuo/IMG_20151115_094802489.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient that $A\geq B$ and $A\geq C$ where $A=\int_a^b(f(x)+g(x)-1)dx$ and $B=\int_a^bf(x)^2dx$ and $C=\int_a^bg(x)^2dx$. We have $$0\leq(A-B)+(A-C)=(2 A-B-C)=\int_a^b(2f(x)+2g(x)-2-f(x)^2-g(x)^2)dx=$$ $$=\int_a^b(-(1-f(x))^2-(1-g(x))^2)dx.$$ So if $b>a$ ,the continuity of $f$ and $g$ imply that $f(x)=g(x)=1$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.